# Hi, I am looking for word that includes following meanings: Children, Seniors, Disabilities

Tags: word-request

I am looking for word that includes following meanings:

```
Children, Seniors, Disabilities
```

I already searched google, and it shows me words like, "Disadvantages," and "Social Minorities."

However, these words are inappropriate for using in my sentence.

Thanks for reading it and hope I can get word ! :)

Comment: Do you mean someone with a disability?  You're looking for one word to describe three very different groups of people.  It really depends on what you're trying to say about these groups,  but my guess would be vulnerable populations.

Comment: @ColleenV I am looking for word that stands for group of people who are socially weak. The word, "Social Minorities" seems too go far for me :(

Comment: It's probably best not to use a single word.

Comment: You call them 'the weak'.

Comment: Please show us what sentence you are trying to write? I don't think there is a suitable word, but it might depend on the sentence you have in mind.

Comment: As @Rathony says, context matters. If you're trying to name a price category for those three groups, that's different from talking about social policies for those three groups.

Comment: Some children are richer than us. A lot of senior people are socially more powerful than us. Some people who have no legs can run even faster than us. I'm not sure that *the weak* is really suitable, unless, of course, it's used subjectively in some context you might have in mind.

Comment: These terms, as I think you are using them, refer to the way such groups are viewed by outsiders, unfortunately often as weak or disadvantaged somehow. Often these terms are using in legal contexts to confer some rights of others to them, which might otherwise be denied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Children, seniors (elderly persons/the old) and the disabled are usually physically or mentally weak. I think 'the weak'  is the term that can be used for such a group of persons.

However, it's better to use these words individually.

Comment: This is not correct. It is a matter of how such groups are usually treated, not how they usually are.

Comment: Studies usually refer to these groups as vulnerable,  not weak.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there's not a single word used exclusively for children, seniors, and the disabled.  I think the OP is looking for a term that he can use  in general for weak people.  There's no denying the fact  that 'the weak'" are mostly children, seniors, and the disabled.

Comment: Weak has a much different connotation than vulnerable. Children, the disabled, and the elderly can be more vulnerable to infection, abuse, poverty et. al. They may be more vulnerable to some things because they are physically weak (not all disabled people are though), but weak doesn't cover all of the ways they could be vulnerable.